# Use an m3u/xspf playlist when an mp3 stream goes offline

Tags: html, css, mp3, onerror, m3u

I'm running a radio station that has two streams - a main one and another one, backup one. However, I'm not quite sure how to use the on-error tag to switch from `.mp3` to `.m3u`. Any solutions?

Site code, for reference if needed [click here](https://github.com/lfhhradio/lfhhradio.github.io/blob/master/index.html)

Comment: The link goes to 404, can you update it?

Comment: @LL updated, thanks for the heads-up